# Docker password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a docker-compose file to launch some services. But the db service is a trouble maker, I always get this error:

`FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "postgres".
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"`

I've read a lot of threads, and I've correctly set the POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD. I have also remove the previous volumes and container to force postgresql to re-init the password. But I can't figure out why it's still not working.

So what is the correct way to force the re-initialization of the postgresql image. So I would be able to connect to my database.

I've seen that this error: `Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"`, and I've heard about the postgres conf file. But it's an official container it's supposed to work, isn't it ?

```
version: '3'
services:
  poll:
    build: poll
    container_name: "poll"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    networks:
      - poll-tier
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build: worker
    container_name: "worker"
    networks:
      - back-tier
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: "redis"
    networks:
      - poll-tier
      - back-tier

  result:
    build: result
    container_name: "result"
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - RESULT_PORT=80
    networks:
      - result-tier
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "postgres:alpine"
    container_name: "db"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back-tier
      - result-tier
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  poll-tier: {}
  back-tier: {}
  result-tier: {}
```

I'm expected to get the db connected, and not `password authentication failed for user "postgres"`.

Comment: Have you tried `bash`-ing into one of the non-`db` containers, install postgres, and then try to `psql -h db -c "select 1" postgres postgres`?  I'm curious to know if the application is storing the wrong password

Comment: I had to delete my volumes and bindings to make it work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your APPs (not the database container) are actually using the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` variables. I suspect they are looking for something like `DB_USER` or similar and so aren't getting the right values in.

By default, every PostgreSQL database driver and admin tool defaults to the `postgres` user. This may explain why the error message complains about `postgres` even if the environment variable isn't being used.

A good way to verify is to change all references to the database user in the docker-compose file to something like `postgres2`. I suspect you'll still see apps complaining that password auth failed for `postgres`.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it was caused by `postgres.exe` service on Windows 10 running in the background. When I stopped the service, uninstalled PostgreSQL 12 from Windows, and restarted, I could finally connect to Postgres Docker container.

EDIT: Stopping the service may also work until the next start, of course. Or you can disclude the service from auto startup.

Comment: THANK YOU, you are a lifesaver! I've been searching for the root cause for a long time, and this has finally helped! Also, it was enough for me just to disable the postgresql service in msconfig (win + R and type msconfig and hit enter)

Comment: @Banik you saved me a lot of hours because I completely forgot I installed postgres in the past, so it wouldn't have been easy to fix!
I confirm that disabling the service was enough for me

Comment: On Linux too, after next start

Answer (score 0):

You need to add: `connect_timeout=5`

Example:

```
postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable&connect_timeout=5
```