# Database in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create a test database, using the postgres docker image, as explained [here](https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/database-in-a-docker-container-how-to-start-and-whats-it-about-5e3ceea77e50)

The difference is that I'm running it using `docker run -d --net host --name my-postgres-container my-postgres-image`.

When I try to connect to the db, using Dbeaver, I get `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`. If I try to not use the local host, but map the port as depict in the link, I get `Connection Refused`. I [read](https://samiprogramming.medium.com/localhost-postgres-docker-connection-refused-using-pgadmin-a27b91de7342) that I should, in that case, replace the localhost by the ip presented when using `docker inspect [container id]`. But there's nothing there:

```
"Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "5f1358819f5ce262fc1ca2ed0d56a77a78601ecd863105d8fad67f2c01aa8606",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

I don't know how to properly create and connect using this strategy.

Comment: How's your networking for `postgresql` and `Dbeaver`? Do you use `docker-compose` file?

Answer (score 0):

When you run postgres you have to pass `user` and `password` as environment parameters.[Kong - postgres example](https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/)

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
               --network=kong-net \
               -p 5432:5432 \
               -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
               -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" \
               postgres:9.6
```

Here you had used your own image for PostgreSQL.

Make sure your have followings in your `Dockerfile`

```
ENV POSTGRES_USER $USER
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD $PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I findout a workaround here for my case when searching for solutions of the same error. I see that you miss some information in your docker-compose or .env file, in the comments above. In case you done all that and run into the same problem with proper command. Try:

1. Run psql in your container.
   If it works fine, but you can't connect from Dbeaver, maybe your localhost port 5432 is conflicting with postgres service on your OS, so stop it for now.
2. On Windows (like me), you can do it via cmd, or simply stop the service in the Task Manager.

Reference:
[Docker password authentication failed for user "postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562024/docker-password-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres)